# ipmitool not functioning the same after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I currently have a se7501br2 motherboard that functions in a server running ubuntu 14.04.  I have recently update to 14.04 from 12.04.  Before this upgrade, I was able to use "ipmitool sensor" to get a readout of processor temperature, fan speed, and a couple other things.  After this upgrade, ipmitool now yields the following:

```
Baseboard 1.2V   | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
Get SDR 0002 command failed: Unspecified error
Get SDR 0002 command failed: Unspecified error
Get SDR 0002 command failed: Unspecified error
Get SDR 0002 command failed: Unspecified error
Get SDR 0002 command failed: Unspecified error
```

Also, ipmi-sensors does function the same as before the update.

Thanks for your suggestions!